# Why the number is rounded over ssh?

Tags: shell, ssh, awk, quoting

```sh
localhost:~ $ df -k / | awk '{print $3/1024/1024/1024}'
0
0.00618061

localhost:~ $ ssh localhost "df -k / | awk '{print $3/1024/1024/1024}'"
01
01
```

Comment: `$3` is being substituted in your shell, before `ssh` sees it.

Comment: @MichaelHomer is right - what your localhost sees is `df -k / | awk '{print /1024/1024/1024}' `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need more quoting when you pass arguments to SSH. Try this:

```
ssh localhost "df -k / | awk '{print \$3/1024/1024/1024}'"
0
0.00623375
```

Note the `\` before `$3`.